# Modal dialog closing immediately

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with the modal dialog, it activates when the user push and input button, then the modal dialog shows, and disappears immediately without do it anything.

The code:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
    }
    dialog.load(
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) {
                dialog.remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            //height: 140,
            //width: 460
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })
    );
    return true;
});
```

Besides, how can I make that, when the user push ok in the modal dialog, the event continues?

Comment: Call your event in button "OK" handler.

Comment: thanks! i'm going to try it!, any clue why i', having problems with the modal dialog? it closes inmediatly it appears?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't wait for the user to click any button?

Comment: yes, just show, ant then hide, and the event continues without the "ok" of the modal dialog

Comment: Can you try with commenting the "RETURN TRUE" just before the ending brackets?

Comment: Try adding e.preventDefault(); as your first line in the function.  The submit action of your form may be causing the dialog to close out.  Also, as said above, get rid of the last return true; statement.  It is unnecessary.  If you still need the form to POST, use the .post() method or .ajax() methods of jQuery to get the data back to the server.

Comment: Can you try http://jsfiddle.net/abhie16/7Gm57/

Comment: Try making changes with jsfiddle. It may help you. I am off for today. Happy weekend.:)

Comment: yes alredy try it, i have the same problem with the dialog, it disappears, without any click or something ..

btw thanks man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add e.preventDefault();

and submit the form on Ok button click after set true to isConfirmed

```
var isConfirmed = false;


$('form').submit(function(e) {
               if(!isConfirmed){
                    var dialog = $("#dialog");
                    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
                    }
                    dialog.load(
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            close: function(event, ui) {
                                dialog.remove();
                            },
                            resizable: false,
                            //height: 140,
                            //width: 460
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "Ok": function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    isConfirmed=true;
                                    $("form").submit();
                                },
                                Cancel: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    );
                   e.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
               else
                  return true;
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you can try:

```
buttons: {
                                "Ok": function() {
                                    //Call your event here. 
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                },
                                Cancel: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had both bootstrap files at the end of my code:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Then I removed bootsrap.min.js and it worked, also I included at the end:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also verify that your a-tag href is "#". I did not have these and the link auto-submits. With the hash it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
    $('#modalID').modal('show');
```

Use this :

```
    $('#modalID').dailog('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the event propagates as expected just return true from the corresponding method.

```
"Ok": function() {
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, meanwhile I shifted to advanced version of Modal Dialog box. The creator named it Nifty dailog box for some reason.

You can access documentation from [Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/)